# Extract IP address after pattern is found in log file

Tags: awk, grep

I need to extract and then block a certain IP address (IPv4 only) within a log file using `ipset` command within a bash script. The logfile structure looks like this:

```
[Line 1] random text
[Line 2] random text
...
[Line 26] random text
Aug 31 13:40:14 [logs ] con_accept: [759] connection from 127.0.0.1:56860 is successfull on 0.0.0.0:25000
[Line 28] random text
...
[Line 38] random text
Aug 31 13:40:57 [logs ] _authrequest: [759] random text client connected and the sky is blue today more random text
[Line 40] random text
```

- Forgot to add that each line `[Line 1] ... [Line X` starts with a timestamp `Aug 31 13:40:14 [logs ] con_accept: [759] connection from 127.0.0.1:56860 is successful on 0.0.0.0:25000`
- The IP address that needs to be extracted and blocked will be displayed within the last 15 lines before the line that matches the pattern. In this case, can be found at `Line 27`.
- The script is first searching for `sky is blue` string
- When the string is found, it prints the last `15 lines` before the matched string line and extracts the IP address that matches `[759]` which is the `clientID`
- To avoid false-positive and wrong blocks the `[ID]` must match, in this case `[759]` matches at `Line 39 and Line 27`. The `clientID` is not a predefined number so it will change. It can only be a number.
- IPv4 address `127.0.0.1` will be extracted and then blocked using `ipset add blacklist $IP`

So far, I'm either for `grep` or `awk` usage. Checking the last 15 lines after pattern has been found is easy, however, I'm trying to do extra checks and extract the correct IP address once the `string is found` and `clientID` match.

```
awk 'c-->0;$0~s{if(b)for(c=b+1;c>1;c--)print r[(NR-c+1)%b];print;c=a}b{r[NR%b]=$0}' b=15 s="sky is blue" logfile

grep -B 15 'sky is blue' logfile
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never additionally need grep (or sed) when you're using awk.

If you have `tac` on your system then:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ip=$(
    tac "${@:--}" |
    awk -v b=15 -v s='sky is blue' '
        $0 ~ s {
            endNr = NR + b
            id = $2
        }
        ($6 == "con_accept:") && ($7 == id) {
            sub(/:.*/,"",$5)
            ip = $10
        }
        NR == endNr { exit }
        END {
            if ( ip == "" ) {
                exit 1
            }
            else {
                print ip
            }
        }
    '
) &&
echo ipset add blacklist "$ip"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
ipset add blacklist 127.0.0.1
```

otherwise less efficiently using GNU awk for arrays of arrays:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ip=$(
    awk -v b=15 -v s='sky is blue' '
        { id = $7 }
        $6 == "con_accept:" {
            sub(/:.*/,"",$10)
            ips[NR][id] = $10
        }
        $0 ~ s {
            for (n=NR-1; n>(NR-b); n--) {
                if ( (n in ips) && (id in ips[n]) ) {
                    ip = ips[n][id]
                    exit
                }
            }
        }
        END {
            if ( ip == "" ) {
                exit 1
            }
            else {
                print ip
            }
        }
    ' "${@:--}"
) &&
echo ipset add blacklist "$ip"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
ipset add blacklist 127.0.0.1
```

Remove the `echo` when you're done testing and happy with the results.

The above assumes that the `[Line N]` strings at the start of each line in your question aren't really present. If they are it's an easy tweak to add 2 to each field number use.

Comment: Thank you, @Ed Morton. I think this is why the script is failing at the moment since each line does start with a timestamp in the following format `Aug 31 13:40:14 [logs ] con_accept: [759] connection from 127.0.0.1:56860 is successful on 0.0.0.0:25000`

Comment: Don;t post sample input/output that doesn't look like your real data as that makes it much harder for us to help you parse your real data. Please [edit] your question to show some more truly representative sample input/output.

Comment: Sorry about that, I left the timestamp aside at first forgetting it could change the entire result. I have updated with proper data, included `random text` where the text is actually random.

Comment: I updated my answer to match (just added 5 to every field number). If `random  text` really is random then you have a problem because then it could match any of the text we're trying to find on the other lines.

Comment: Thank you @Ed Morton, this works great now. Since the client can have a different IP address later on is it possible to run the script for all the IP addresses that matches the `string` +`clientID` within the previous 15 lines before the matching string line?

Comment: eg: If the string is found twice in the logfile and first time the client has IP 127.0.0.1, then later in the logfile the client connected again but with a different IP 192.168.1.0, the script shall only blacklist the first matching result which is the 127.0.0.1 IP and not the second too.

Comment: I meant to be part of the same script but applies to all the results not just the first one. Wouldn't be marked as a duplicate question if I do that?

Comment: No, just say it's a followup to this one (and provide the link to it) and state the differences, e.g. multiple occurrences of IP addresses or "sky is blue" or whatever and you'll be showing a different [mcve] with different code (mine plus whatever you try to do to it yourself to solve the new problem) plus different sample input/output.

Answer (score 2):

A simple first pass:

```
grep -nB 15 'sky is blue' logfile | sort -nr
```

The `grep -n` will preface each line with its line number from the file (format: `<line_number>:<contents_of_line>`).

The `sort -rn` will sort the rows in reverse order using numeric sorting.

From here you can pass these lines to a `bash/while` loop or `awk` script, keeping in mind several (potential) issues:

- what if 'sky is blue' is not found?
- what if 'sky is blue' has multiple matches? process the first, the last or all instances?
- what if a given clientID has multiple matching rows but with different ip addresses? process the first, the last or all ip addresses?
- do all lines of interest have the same exact formats as displayed in the sample data or could there be different formats that need to be coded for?

'course, all of this could be coded in a dozen different ways via a single `awk` script (eg, Ed Morton's answer) ...

Comment: If `sky is blue` is not found simply ignore the script. If `sky is blue` has multiple matches process all instances. If a given clientID has multiple matching rows but with different ip addresses then process all IP addresses. If this is not possible I could truncate the logfile after each match is found and the script runs.

Comment: @Brian-reins please update the question with these additional details; not everyone is going to peruse the comments trying to piece together the entire picture

Comment: Sorry about that markp, I left the timestamp aside at first forgetting it could change the entire result. I have updated with proper data, included `random text` where the text is actually random.

Comment: I was referring to adding your comments to the question, re: multiple occurrences of 'sky is blue' and multiple ips for a given clientID (within the last 15 rows)

Comment: Thanks markp. I did give an answer to that: multiple occurences of 'sky is blue' and multiple ips for a given clientID are possible but not within the last 15 rows.  Ed's solution works like a charm just that the script only processes the first IP address and I would need to process all the IP addresses that match the `string` + `clientID` since the IP address can be different.

Comment: Sorry that I cannot upvote your answers as very useful as well, I do not have the required reputation to do so yet but I appreciate your help.